# Why Qd1 is the best move?

Tags: stockfish, online-chess

[image]

As per subject, why Qd1 is the best move and all other moves for queen like Qd2 and Qd3 are not? I understand that it’s important to cover d column but why 1 and not 2 or 3?

Also why Rd1 is not a good move?

Comment: It looks like chess.com's puzzle service. You can often look for details in the comments section, people usually provide there correct answers and common mistakes

Comment: I play from mobile app and there are no comments for daily puzzle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Qd1 hits the bishop on d6 and the knight on h5. One of those will be won.

Btw, I think this a famous game between Larry Christiansen and Anatoly Karpov. Famous, of course for this early blunder. [Here, you can see the whole game and maybe find out more about the players.](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1069116)

Comment: Aaah now I see, i feel stupid now. Thanks

Comment: Black was a world champion. If he missed this, you can too. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Qd1 wins a piece attacking both d6 and h5.